# input.text_area - want to use variable for defval

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to assign a variable for defval but it says that it needs to be a constant.

```
string pair = syminfo.ticker + " long entry"
i_alert_txt_entry_long = input.text_area(defval = pair, title = "Long Entry Message", group = "Alerts")
```

Is it possible to do in pine script currently?

I have tried other options such as str.tostring to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

For input.text_area, defval must be a const string.
And there is no way in Pinescript (<=v5) to get a constant string from a string.

As stated in the pinescript manual:

> Values of “const” form must be known at compile time, before your script has access to any information related to the symbol/timeframe information it is running on. Compilation occurs when you save a script in the Pine Script™ Editor, which doesn’t even require it to already be running on your chart. “const” variables cannot change during the execution of a script.